# Incorporate a feature branch into my feature branch without causing conflicts when squashed to master

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

So the tree currently looks something like this:

```
       B--F     <-- feature/a: colleague's feature branch (on review, squashed when merged)
      /
...--A--C--E    <-- master
         \
          D--G  <-- feature/b: my feature branch (wip)
```

What I need is to copy changes from `feature/a` to `feature/b` without having conflicts after `feature/a` is merged as a squash commit.

The desired outcome should look something like this:

```
       B--F             <-- feature/a (squash merged as commit H)
      /
...--A--C--E--H (--J)   <-- master (J is not present yet, master is at H)
         \
          D--G--B'--F'  <-- feature/b (will be merged later as squash commit J)
```

I need a way to copy `feature/a`, without git thinking `B` and `F` are duplicate changes when my branch will be sqash-merged.

Last time I did something similiar I was flooded by conflicts, because squash commit `J` didn't have direct history with `F` (no pointer from `H` to `F`), so `F'` was considered duplicate.

Comment: you should rebase `feature/b` on `master` or merge `master` into `feature/b`

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think that works. `H` is nonexistent at the moment, so merging master right now would give me a pointer to `E`, but not to `H`. When `H` will be created I will still get the `F != F'` conflict when it's my turn to merge my branch back into master.

Comment: If you're going to squash your branch into `master`, does it matter what you do? The changes on both sides will collapse.

Comment: BTW, if you're asking about how to quickly resolve those potential conflicts before you complete your squash merge, you could probably resolve them after `H` exists by merging `master` into `feature/b` with `git merge origin/master -Xours`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I need is to copy changes from feature/a to feature/b without having conflicts after feature/a is merged as a squash commit.

You can't, in general.  But you may be able to get what you need.

Two commits are really *the same* commit under two different conditions:

- They have the same commit hash ID.  Then they are literally the same commit: there's really only the one commit.  This is how Git knows that some commit in *some other repository* is the same as the commit in *this* repository.
- They have the same *patch-id* (see [the `git patch-id` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id)).

When someone uses `git merge --squash`, they get a new commit—i.e., one with a different *hash* ID—whose *patch* ID is almost certain to be different from the patch-IDs of the individual commits.  That's because a patch ID is a cryptographic checksum of a stripped-down diff (see the documentation for details): if the squash commit's diff matches, the patch ID matches, but if not, it doesn't.  If the squash commit is the result of squashing *two or more* commits, it will have a single patch ID that won't match any of the individual patch IDs of any of the individual commits, none of which produces that particular diff: you only get that particular diff by *summing together* the individual commits.

**What you can do is simple enough though.**  Instead of cherry-picking in all the `feature/a` commits, *do your own `git merge --squash`.  This will get you a *single commit*, which we can call `H'`, that will have the *same patch ID* as the future `H`, provided that `H` is built by merge-squashing `B` and `F` into `E` *and* the diff isn't too disturbed by this merge-squash effect.

That is, `H'` will make the same *changes* to `G` that `B`+`F` will make to `E`.  The line numbers might differ, along with some other information that `git patch-id` drops, but as long as the stuff that is different gets stripped out, the patch ID will match.

A future `git rebase` will drop the patch-ID-equivalent `H'`.  So you can simply *rebase* `feature/b` *onto* `master` once `H` exists, and switch from using your `H'` to using their `H`.  Of course this has all the usual drawbacks of any rebase, but it is automatic, and removes duplication that might otherwise potentially cause merge conflicts.

(Duplication that is an *exact* duplicate is elided by `git merge`.  This includes the merge-as-a-verb process that `git merge --squash` uses before it makes a non-merge-commit, where "merge" is an adjective.  However, depending on what's in each of the various commits, your chances of avoiding conflicts are usually improved by this `H`-vs-`H'` trickery.)

Your best bet, of course, is to avoid copying `feature/a` into `feature/b` at all until commit `H` exists, and rebasing then, but if you find that you need `feature/a`, this may let you get there less painfully.

Comment: Pretty thorough explanation, much appreciated!